# Handle Secure Cookie with HttpURLConnection and Domain

Tags: java, servlets, httpcookie

I would need to exchange with my backend server a Cookie with Secure, HttpOnly and Domain flags.

Here the code I'm using for the client:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SESSION", session);            
cookie.setDomain("example.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setMaxAge(1000);
cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI("https://example.com"), cookie);            
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
....
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

and on the servlet side I'm using:

```
Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
        log.debug("Cookie: " + cookie[i].getName() + " " + cookie[i].getValue());
        if (cookie[i].getName().equals("SESSION")) {
            log.debug("Received session: " + cookie[i].getValue());
            log.debug("is secured ?: "+cookie[i].getSecure());
            log.debug("Max age: "+cookie[i].getMaxAge());
            log.debug("Domain: "+cookie[i].getDomain());
            tokenUser = cookie[i].getValue();
        }
    }
```

I can retrieve the Cookie SESSION but flags Secure, HttpOnly or Domain are not set (in fact I only get the value of the token).

How can I ensure that Cookie received on the server side are set correctly ? may be I'm missing something ?

Comment: Server sets the cookie and flags, not the client. Server doesn’t care about those flags, they exist to tell the client (browser) how to handle your cookie. They therefore exist only on the `Set-Cookie` header, not on the `Cookie` header (which the client uses for returning a cookie to the server). It might help if you explain what you’re trying to do - why is the client manually setting a session header?

Comment: I need to send session cookie to the server to manage authentification. I tought that by using cookie it was the right way...

Comment: The server sends the cookie. The client returns it. A cookiemanager will handle this for you. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/CookieManager.html